# AngularDart interface tests

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm using this command to run tests in my application:

`pub run angular_test --test-arg=--tags=aot --test-arg=--platform=dartium  --test-arg=--reporter=expanded --serve-arg=--hostname=192.168.173.1 --serve-arg=--port=8180 --verbose`

But when my tests run, I got this:

`Failed to load "test\app_test.dart":
Error getting http://localhost:8180/app_test.dart.browser_test.dart: The remote computer refused the network connection.
(errno 1225)
Make sure "pub serve" is running.`

How I can change the call to `localhost`? Should not the call follow `--serve-arg=--hostname=192.168.173.1` config?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, why are you passing the hostname?

Comment: To run my application, I use a custom hostname, because I have local dns names, docker images to services, and another things. My objective is test a full application.

Comment: There was just a commit today that got angular_test updated. Perhaps this fixes the issue.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I searched in the repository but not found something related to the question. Can you link the source?